# Convert to and from Unix Timestamp

Tags: time, rtc, data-type

What is the best way to convert between date, hours, min, seconds to Unix timestamp in milliseconds in Arduino? I need to have this conversion, since I'm using RTC (date, hours, min, secs etc) and communicating Unix timestamp over BLE

I found some snippet of codes online, but have not tested it extensively yet.

```cpp
  byte second = epoch%60; epoch /= 60;
  byte minute = epoch%60; epoch /= 60;
  byte hour   = epoch%24; epoch /= 24;

  unsigned int years = epoch/(365*4+1)*4; epoch %= 365*4+1;
  unsigned int year;
  for (year=3; year>0; year--)
  {
      if (epoch >= days[year][0])
          break;
  }

  unsigned int month;
  for (month=11; month>0; month--)
  {
      if (epoch >= days[year][month])
          break;
  }

  year  = years+year;
  month = month+1;
  unsigned int day   = epoch - days[year][month]+1;

  unsigned int weekday  = (dayOfMonth += month < 3 ? year-- : year - 2, 23*month/9 + dayOfMonth + 4 + year/4- year/100 + year/400)%7;
```

And to convert to Unix timestamp:

```cpp
unsigned long epoch = (((year/4*(365*4+1)+days[year%4][month]+dayOfMonth)*24+hour)*60+minute)*60+second;
```

Are there any library in Arduino that implement this? I would trade off reliability over size of the program.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the two most used libraries are the [Adafruit RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) and the [pjrc.com TimeLib](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Time.html).
They both have functions to convert the epoch, and they both are reliable. But both lack the timezone and the DaylightSavingTime.
I think you find the pjrc.com TimeLib just slightly more suitable to handle the epoch time (which is a 32-bit unsigned long defined as 'time_t').

Comment: +1 for TimeLib. I use it all the time for unix timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard way of doing those conversions in C, which is
through the functions defined in `<time.h>`. This API being standard,
you can test it in your computer. Recent versions of the avr-libc
support this: see [time.h in avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html). These functions can handle
local time if you provide a function implementing the DST rules: see
`set_dst()`. Examples are provided for US and EU rules.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that the 'time.h' with timezone and also DST were included with the Arduino. Thanks. To connect a RTC chip with that time system is sadly not nice. Every second a system_tick() should be called. I just stay with the pjrc.com TimeLib for now.

Comment: @Jot That's not entirely correct. You can use a RTC to set the Arduino's internal clock, then call the internal clock for needed time info ... RTC in that case is merely a battery backed clock that is OCCASIONALLY used ... once per reboot and possibly every week or two for drift correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to convert seconds (Unix time) to Date & Time using TimeLib.h:

```
#include <TimeLib.h>

unsigned long offset_days = 3;    // 3 days
unsigned long t_unix_date1, t_unix_date2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  t_unix_date1 = 1564398600;
  Serial.print("t_unix_date1: ");
  Serial.println(t_unix_date1);
  offset_days = offset_days * 86400;    // convert number of days to seconds
  t_unix_date2 = 1564398600 + offset_days;
  Serial.print("t_unix_date2: ");
  Serial.println(t_unix_date2);
  printf("Date1: %4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", year(t_unix_date1), month(t_unix_date1), day(t_unix_date1), hour(t_unix_date1), minute(t_unix_date1), second(t_unix_date1));
  printf("Date2: %4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", year(t_unix_date2), month(t_unix_date2), day(t_unix_date2), hour(t_unix_date2), minute(t_unix_date2), second(t_unix_date2));
}

void loop() {



}
```